# Stackover flow created by onCreatePreferences

Tags: java, android, preferences

When calling a preference fragment from my main activity, the preference fragment always crashes due to a stack overflow error caused by `onCreatePreferences` being called multiple times.

I have other fragments that load and run just fine, but they extend `Fragment` and not `PreferenceFragmentCompat`.  I pulled the code directly from the android documentation. Also I'm using `androidx` throughout the app.

```java
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new   BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    selected = MapFragment.newInstance();
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    selected = new PreferencesFragment();
                    break;
                default:
                    selected = OffersFragment.newInstance(1);
                    break;

            }


            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selected).commit();

            return true;
        }
    };


    ....


   static class PreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {


        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
        }
        // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI    event




    }
```

```
08-15 11:24:47.857 28789-28789/com.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL        EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xxx, PID: 28789
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
    at       androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreate(PreferenceFragment    Compat.java:141)
    at     com.xxx.MainActivity$PreferencesFragment.onCreatePreferences(MainActivity.java:138)

 D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError
 ERR: exMsg=stack size 8MB
 ERR: file=PreferenceFragmentCompat.java
 ERR: class=androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
 ERR: method=onCreate line=141
 ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
```

This is the actual error I get.  I'm not sure why `onCreatePreference` keeps getting called.

Comment: You're calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in `onCreatePreferences()`. Don't do that.

Comment: @MikeM. That did it. Thank you very much.